# Removing an optional / (directory separator) in Bash

Tags: bash, replace

I have a Bash script that takes in a directory as a parameter, and after some processing will do some output based on the files in that directory.

The command would be like the following, where `dir` is a directory with the following structure inside

```
dir/foo
dir/bob
dir/haha
dir/bar
dir/sub-dir
dir/sub-dir/joe

> myscript ~/files/stuff/dir
```

After some processing, I'd like the output to be something like this

```
foo
bar
sub-dir/joe
```

The code I have to remove the path passed in is the following:

```
shopt -s extglob

for file in $files ; do
    filename=${file#${1}?(/)}
```

This gets me to the following, but for some reason the optional `/` is not being taken care of. Thus, my output looks like this:

```
/foo
/bar
/sub-dir/joe
```

The reason I'm making it optional is because if the user runs the command

```
> myscript ~/files/stuff/dir/
```

I want it to still work. And, as it stands, if I run that command with the trailing slash, it outputs as desired.

So, why does my `?(/)` not work? Based on everything I've read, that should be the right syntax, and I've tried a few other variations as well, all to no avail.

Thanks.

Comment: `#` matches as short as possible so the optional part will never be included. You could use `##` to match as long possible

Comment: @thatotherguy, that worked! Ah! Didn't see anything about that in the documentation. If you want to put that as an answer, I'll accept it when I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the documentation from `man bash` under "Parameter Expansion":

```
   ${parameter#word}
   ${parameter##word}
          Remove   matching  prefix  pattern.   The  word  is
          expanded to produce a pattern just as  in  pathname
          expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of
          the value of parameter,  then  the  result  of  the
          expansion  is  the expanded value of parameter with
          the shortest matching pattern (the ``#''  case)  or
          the  longest  matching  pattern  (the  ``##'' case)
          deleted.
```

Since `#` tries to delete the shortest match, it will never include any trailing optional parts.

You can just use `##` instead:

```
    filename=${file##${1}?(/)}
```

Depending on what your script does and how it works, you can also just rewrite it to `cd` to the directory to always work with paths relative to `.`

Answer (score 4):

[that other guy's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38298691/45375) solves your immediate problem, but there are two things worth nothing:

- enumerating filenames with an unquoted string variable (`for file in $files`) is ill-advised, as [sjsam's helpful answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38298621/45375) points out: it will break with filenames with embedded spaces and filenames that look like globs; as stated, storing filenames in an *array* is the robust choice.
- there is no strict need to change global shell option `shopt -s extglob`: parameter expansions can be *nested*, so the following would work without changing shell options:

```
# Sample values:
file='dir/sub-dir/joe'
set -- 'dir/'  # set $1; value 'dir' would have the same effect.

filename=${file#${1%/}}  # -> '/sub-dir/joe'
```

The inner parameter expansion, `${1%/}`, removes a trailing (`%`) `/` from `$1`, if any.

Answer (score 3):

I suggested you change `files` to an array which is a possible workaround for non-standard filenames that may contain spaces.

```
files=("dir/A/B" "dir/B" "dir/C")
for filename in "${files[@]}"
do
  echo ${filename##dir/} #replace dir/ with your param.
done
```

**Output**

```
A/B
B
C
```